# Jquery Accordion - Expand and collapse div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a basic implementation of the accordion but not close to what i want it to be.

**Link:**
http://jsfiddle.net/mwqhp/

Jquery code:

```
$(function () {
                $('.box').hover(function () {
                    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
                        width: '+=300',
                        height: '+=300'
                    }, 500);
                }, function () {
                    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
                        width: '-=300',
                        height: '-=300'
                    },500)
                });
            });
```

Here's the link to what i wanted to replicate from.  This is the sprint's homepage.
http://www.sprint.com/mysprint/pages/sl/global/index.jsp

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems you've already achieved the same functionality minus the fades. What exactly else do you want to do?

Comment: Do you want the rectangles to grow upwards and be in the bottom?

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall - I wanted it to go upwards instead of downward and be able to fade to show a different content.  Just like how it's implemented in the Sprint site but i'm not able replicate it.  Any help?

Comment: @Sergio Yes and be able to show a content when the box is opened up.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Can you hit the green check mark for my answer?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwqhp/12/)**

```
(function($) {
    $('.box').hover(function() {

        $this = $(this),
        $oC = $this.find('.oldContent'),
        $nC = $this.find('.newContent');

        $oC.stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');

        $this.stop(true, true).animate({
            width: '+=300',
            height: '+=300',
            bottom: '+=300'
        }, function() {
            $nC.fadeIn('fast');
        });

    }, function() {

        $nC.stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');

        $this.stop(true, true).animate({
            width: '-=300',
            height: '-=300',
            bottom: '-=300'
        }, function() {
            $oC.fadeIn('fast');
        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

It is working better but still sometimes shows older content. Working on fix.

Comment: Thanks! @shivam - Can you prevent the content from popping in and out?  When i hover all three from left to right, contents kept popping in and out for several times.  But this seems to do the job.

Comment: Can you possibly show different content on original state and different content when hovered and expanded?

Comment: I updated the fiddle with my current progress. Still working on fixing the fast hover shows older content bug.

Comment: Can i suggest of adding a set width for all three boxes? Meaning not have to push the boxes outward when the box expands.

Comment: Hmm, this is the best i could do at the moment :). I believe the script I provided answered your question & should give you a good head start on continuing with this project.

Comment: It's okay.  I can take it from here.  Thanks for the answer and your time put into this.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/mwqhp/1/

```
<div>
    <div class=" div4"></div>
    <div class=" div5"></div>
    <div class=" div6"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="box div1"></div>
        <div class="box div2"></div>
        <div class="box div3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
#container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -300px;
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.div1 {
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
}
.div2 {
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
.div3 {
    background: pink;
    float: left;
}
body>div {
    width: 800px;
}
.div4 {
    height:20px;
    width: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
}
.div5 {
    width: 100px;
    height:20px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
.div6 {
    height:20px;
    width: 100px;
    background: pink;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I think OP want's the boxes on bottom and opening upwards.

Comment: you mean the fix divs at bottom and the expansive ones at the top?

Comment: NO, just 3 boxes, growing from the bottom of the page. Like the url OP posted.

Comment: Yes, if that's possible. Thanks for replying guys.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: oh ok I'm sorry I was looking at the nav - I apologize

Comment: I guess u got your answer underneath  maybe a little padding or margin between boxes and you have what you want.